Everything seems to be fine like the path etc. but why I am getting a import error?
So i am gonna be straight. I am doing a project of a Expense Tracker in vs code. My workspace is clean i have only one directory in this work space so i can work without hassle. By the way this is a git hub rep so i saved and started to work on it.
[This is where the problem seems to be]
(https://i.sstatic.net/ewrrV.png)
Now to the main problem. So, I have checked folder, file paths is vs code updated or not ,etc.
[This is where I write code for the app]
(https://i.sstatic.net/aHy6d.png)
The error:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from expense import Expense

ImportError: cannot import name 'Expense' from 'expense' (h:\Python intermediate course+data science\Expense-System-1\expense.py)

I have 2 main files one is where i write the code(maintracker.py) and (expense.py) one which is the structure or whatever you call it.
[The error image:]
(https://i.sstatic.net/c2JS9.png)
I mean I tried almost everything, searched in google , tried prompting ai to help me etc.
I expected this:
Enter amount:(any number)
choose the category:
1.food
2.house bills
3.buisness
Enter:
what I got:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Expense' from 'expense' (h:\Python intermediate course+data science\Expense-System-1\expense.py)


What is your project/file structure and how are you running your code? Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
